# Correctly enqueue scripts of type=text/paperscript (PaperJs Library)

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, library

I need to use Paper.js (http://paperjs.org/), and specifically one of their examples (http://paperjs.org/examples/smoothing/) on a WordPress website.

Usually, scripts are enqued to WP with a PHP function that adds scripts of type text/javascript (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and should be fine for the Paper.js library itself.

But... The script utilizing Paper.js should be of type text/paperscript (http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/), and the only solution I could come up with is echo both script tags to my (child theme to a Genesis Framework) header.php file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-full.min.js" integrity="sha256-qZnxjtwxg51juOcYyANvBWwFoahMFNB2GSkGI5LGmW0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/paperscript' canvas='smoothCanvas' href='../js/smoothing.js'></script>
```

Is there any other solution? I tried to search some tutorials for Paper.js on Wordpress, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Did you add `canvas` with id `smoothCanvas`, like this `<canvas id="smoothCanvas" resize></canvas>`?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Just found out it was not a problem in the HTML, but in the paperscript... I add to declare the smoothing() function to be "exportable", that is window.smoothing = function smoothing(){}

Now the canvas does display the example, but there's no way to interact with it. I'll update the question.

Comment: So, what's the problem now? Need to enqueue with `text/paperscript` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but you can use the `script_loader_tag` filter to change the type `text/javascript` to `text/paperscript`

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
  if( 'your-script-handle' === $handle ) {
    $tag = str_replace( 'text/javascript', 'text/paperscript ', $tag );
  }
  return $tag;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in case there's no `text/javascript` :

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function( $tag, $handle, $src ) {      
      if( 'script_handle' === $handle ) {
          $tag = str_replace( '<script', '<script type="text/paperscript" ', $tag );
      }
      return $tag;
}, 10, 3 );
```